# I want to get a list of files using FirebaseStorage in Flutter, but I can't

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

I am Japanese. I am using automatic translation, so please forgive me if my English is a little strange in places.

Now, my question is, I would like to link FirebaseStorage and Flutter to this video (link below) to get a list of files, but I am having trouble getting it.

Is there any solution?

PS: I am able to link with FireBase.
Note 2: FireBase related packages are also installed.

Link to video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DzdOceMkGHw&t=70s

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:ous/main.dart';

class kiban extends StatefulWidget {
  const kiban({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<kiban> createState() => _kibanState();
}

class _kibanState extends State<kiban> {
  late Future<ListResult> futureFiles;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    futureFiles = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('/files').list();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('基盤教育科目'),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder<ListResult>(
          future: futureFiles,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final files = snapshot.data!.items;

              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: files.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final file = files[index];

                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(file.name),
                    trailing: IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.download,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () => downloadFile(file),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Center(
                child: Text('error'),
              );
            } else {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      );

  Future downloadFile(Reference ref) async {
    final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final file = File('${dir.path}/${ref.name}');
    await ref.writeToFile(file);

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text('ダウンロード中。ちょっと待ってね ${ref.name}')),
    );
  }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you're able to read and write from Firestorage.
If your code does not allow you to read those data, you could get some related information from the console("RUN Page under bottom") in Android studio.
Therefore, we need to change the rules for Firebase Storage to be public, like this:

Before:
[image]
After:
[image]

Comment: Thank you ！！！！ Now I can read it: ！！！！

I'd forgotten how fundamental that is.
I really appreciate it. Seriously, the best!